# Python: Check if a /dev/disk device exists

Tags: python

I am trying to write python script to find out if a disk device exists in /dev, but it always yield False. Any other way to do this?

I tried

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.isfile("/dev/bsd0")
False
>>> os.path.exists("/dev/bsd0")
False

$ ll /dev
...
brw-rw----   1 root disk    252,   0 Nov 12 21:28 bsd0
...
```

Comment: Try `os.path.isabs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was not rigorously tested, but seems to work:

```
import stat
import os.stat

def disk_exists(path):
     try:
             return stat.S_ISBLK(os.stat(path).st_mode)
     except:
             return False
```

Results:

```
disk_exists("/dev/bsd0")
True
disk_exists("/dev/bsd2")
False
```

Comment: I don't think `import os.stat` is needed. (At least with python3)

Comment: Old answer, but in recent version it should be `import os`* and not `os.stat`.

Answer (score 8):

Some unconventional situation is going on here.

[`os.path.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)
will return `True` for regular files, for device files this will be
`False`.

But as for
[`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists),
documetation states that `False` may be returned if "permission is not
granted to execute `os.stat()`". FYI the implementation of
`os.path.exists` is:

```py
def exists(path):
    """Test whether a path exists.  Returns False for broken symbolic links"""
    try:
        os.stat(path)
    except OSError:
        return False
    return True
```

So, if `os.stat` is failing on you I don't see how `ls` could have
succeeded (`ls` AFAIK also calls stat() syscall).  So, check what
`os.stat('/dev/bsd0')` is raising to understand why you're not being
able to detect the existence of this particular device file with
`os.path.exists`, because using `os.path.exists()` is supposed
to be a valid method to check for the existence of a block device file.